# В чем разница между оксюмороном и катахрезой?

Tags: значение-слов

И то и другое - попытка сочетания слов, которые не сочетаются. А в чем отличие этих терминов?

Answer (score 3):

КАТАХРЕЗА или катахрезис (греч. Κατάχρησις, злоупотребление) — стилистический термин, обозначающий такое сочетание слов, в котором их прямой смысл образует ***логическую несогласованность***.

ОКСЮМОРОН (греч. — «острая глупость») — термин античной стилистики, обозначающий нарочитое сочетание ***противоречивых*** понятий. Пример: «Смотри, ей ***весело грустить***/ Такой нарядно-обнаженной» (Ахматова).

***Оксюморон*** отличается как от ***катахрезы***, где отсутствует ***противопоставление*** соединяемых противоречивых слов, так и от ***антитезы***, где нет слияния воедино противопоставленных понятий.

[Оксюморон](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_literature/3452/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD)

Comment: Здесь есть хорошие примеры катахрезы: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0

Comment: Зеленый шум - катахреза, а тихий шум - оксюморон, получается. "Наш шум - тишина, а тишь наша - грохот." - антитеза.